# Can we access methods of The JAR file has no source attachment?

Tags: java

I have a jar file which has no source attachment, rather a compiled set of classes. Would I be able to access those?
Say a class X, which had methods A, B and C and many such classes. We make a jar out of them. If I place together all the compiled classes in a jar, would I be able to use them.
 
Beacause if I try to use. I get a statement

`The JAR file has no source attachment`, which I am confuses is an error, a warning or just telling I can't see the implementation.
PS: Please don't say try and see, I know I should but I am on a clock.
Edit: My source not found snapshot is added.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: At runtime you only need class files

Comment: Where do you get that statement? Seems like this is eclipse telling you it can't show the class's sourcecode while debugging.

Comment: Yes, I am getting a NullPointerException in a project that I am working, I came across this while debugging, and I am wondering if this is the cause.

Comment: Show the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException` and the related class/method

Answer (score 0):

There are eclipse plugins that can help you do what you are trying to do.
I personally have had a lot of luck using this particular one:

https://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/

Hope this helps